# Erro com calc no Safari!

Tags: css

Estou com problemas no Safari 5.1, o css width: calc(100% - 350px); não funciona corretamente no safari, segue o código e o jsfiddle:

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eob01cbf/2/)

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="conteudo2"></div>

#conteudo2 {
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 150px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 150px);
width: calc(100% - 150px);
background-color: #333333;
float: left;
height: 920px;
margin-top: -10px;
}

#menu {
width: 150px;
float: left;
height: 900px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Nos outros navegadores está funcionando corretamente!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função calc só é suportada a partir do safari 6.0.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility

Você pode fazer os cálculos usando javascript, por exemplo:

```
var element1 = document.getElementById('elemento1');
var element2 = document.getElementById('elemento2');
element2.style.width = element1.style.width - 350;
```

Algo assim.

Comment: E qual a melhor solução para esse problema ?

Comment: @AlanPS Fazer esses cálculos com javascript. Vou editar a resposta e mostrar como fazer.